# Instantiating Lua objects through the C API

Tags: c++, lua

I am trying to do some OO functionality in Lua via the C API. In my Lua script I have the following:

```
Parser = {}
Parser.__index = Parser

function Parser:create(url)
    local self = {}
    print ("creating")
    self.baseUrl = url
    setmetatable(self, Parser)
    return self
end

function Parser:Foo()
    print ("baseUrl: " .. self.baseUrl)
end

p = Parser:create("http://www.google.com")
p:Foo()
```

If I run this from the command line, it works fine and I see the following output:

```
creating
baseUrl: http://www.google.com
```

Now, if I comment out the last two lines and try the following through the C API

```
// <load the state and lua file>
lua_getglobal(L, "Parser");
lua_getfield(L, -1, "create");
lua_pushstring(L, "http://www.google.com");

if (lua_pcall(L, 1, 1, 0) != 0)
{
  // handle error
}
```

This works. I see "creating" in my standard output as expected. As I understand it, the new *Parser* object is now on top of the stack. If I them immediately try the following:

```
lua_getfield(L, -1, "Foo");
if (lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0) != 0)
{
  logger()->error("-- %1", lua_tostring(L, -1));
}
```

I get the following error: ***attempt to index local 'self' (a nil value)***

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to get the function to run as expected?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition `function Parser:Foo() ... end` is equivalent to:

```
Parser.Foo = function(self)
    print ("baseUrl: " .. self.baseUrl)
end
```

That is -- `Foo` is a function that takes one argument. When you call `lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0)` you are passing `0` arguments. Change it to `lua_pcall(L, 1, 0, 0)` and everything should work. (You will have to also change the pcall to `create` to correctly pass `2` arguments rather than `1`).

Comment: That is, `a:method(...)` is always equivalent to `a.method(self, ...)`

Comment: To be more precise, the [function call](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4.9) `a:method(params)` is always equivalent to `a.method(a,params)` (except that `a` is only evaluated once), and the [function definition](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4.10) `function a:method(params) body end` is always equivalent to `a.method = function(self, params) body end`.

Comment: Oh dang, I forgot the `function` from those. Indeed. And looks like I can't even edit the first comment anymore.

Comment: I understand why the call to `Foo` requires me to pass `self` but does `create` really need it in this example? When I call it, it's returning me a `self`.

Comment: @Addy: `create` is a function taking two parameters -- `self` and `url`. If you want it to be a function taking one parameter, don't use the colon syntax when defining/using it (that is, define it as `Parser.create = function(url) ... end`)

Comment: @Addy: To explain further, there is nothing special about `self` apart from the fact that it is the name used for the implicit parameter introduced by the colon syntax. Your definition of `create` simply declares a new variable called `self` that shadows the `self` function parameter.